# Xamarin forms: Customize Android Material style status bar color

Tags: xamarin, material-design, xamarin.forms, statusbar, android-theme

I have enabled Material theme on my Xamarin.Forms project with the following code, but on Android (Lollipop and Marshmallow) the top status bar (where the clock, signal, battery, etc.. are located) doesn't change. It remains always black.
I've already read lot of forums and blogs, tried lot of combination but I'm not able to get this status bar colored as I want.

**MainActivity.cs**

```cs
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme", Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@drawable/AppIcon", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

**values-v21/style.xml**

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme.Splash" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">    
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/SplashScreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/Brand</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/White</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/BrandDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/BrandDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/Brand</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Brand</item>    
  </style>  
</resources>
```

**values/colors.xml**

```xml
<resources>  
  <color name="SplashBackground">#f78b2b</color>
  <color name="Brand">#f78b2b</color>
  <color name="BrandDark">#e47108</color>
  <color name="White">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow [this Tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/) to get success.

Basically you have to use `FormsAppCompatActivity` instead of `FormsApplicationActivity` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.Material.Light`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any place or user guide where I can see all possible settings ? For example for changing the color of bar of a text entry, or removing the shadow of buttons, etc..

Comment: This is usually defined in the Android development guide. http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html is a good starting point. But in combination with AppCompat, its always a bit fiddly

Answer (score 4):

Other solution most simply, in method OnCreate of MainActivity.cs add :

`Window window = this.Window;
window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(116, 181, 13));`

Comment: unfortunately xamarin says : **"Java.Lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='setStatusBarColor' signature='(I)V' in class Landroid/view/Window;"**
God I hate xamarin, nothing is guaranteed to work. Why do they release it in the first place?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: Maxime Claude SetStatusBarColor is not available below Android Lollipop add verification if necessary

Answer (score 1):

A translation from the equivalent Java version :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
{
    // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
    Window.ClearFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);

    //Window.ClearFlags(WindowManager.Pa WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    Window.AddFlags(Android.Views.WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);

    // finally change the color
    Window.SetStatusBarColor(new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(this, Resource.Color.colorPrimaryDark)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same as the accepted answer. It was working on one of our projects but not the other.

I have not seen a solution to this particular problem so I am being the first here.

If you have declared your uses-permissions in the assemblyInfo.cs instead of the manifest will cause the status bar not to work as expected.

Even if you get it working by setting it individually for each activity it still doesn't work when you are transitioning to activities. So the only way is to move the uses-permission statements to the manifest.

Hopefully I can help someone!